# Download array as text file with newline

Tags: javascript

So I have this array, and want to create a download text file option, where the array text is included. It works, and the file is downloaded, but it's all in one line, with no newline. Is there a way to create a new line in the `.txt` file, I've made a picture to show what I get vs what I'm trying to get?

```js
var filename = "log.txt";
var text = ['2021-10-06 12:38:15.946 INFO [conftest:101] Global Fixture Setup Started --------------', '2021-10-06 12:38:16.059 INFO [Wrapper:21] Downloading  from ar:', '2021-10-06 12:38:16.061 INFO [Handler:55] …ct: 1/1 - com.grundfos.hvp.xconnect-prerelease:V+', '2021-10-06 12:38:17.561 INFO [SessionManager:52] N…lication/json Content-Type header in GET response', '2021-10-06 12:38:17.632 INFO [SessionManager:52] N…lication/json Content-Type header in GET response'];
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
element.setAttribute('download', filename);

element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);

element.click();

document.body.removeChild(element);
```

[image]

Comment: Join the lines using `\n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and `\n` as a separator :

```js
var filename = "log.txt";
var text = ['2021-10-06 12:38:15.946 INFO [conftest:101] Global Fixture Setup Started --------------', '2021-10-06 12:38:16.059 INFO [Wrapper:21] Downloading  from ar:', '2021-10-06 12:38:16.061 INFO [Handler:55] …ct: 1/1 - com.grundfos.hvp.xconnect-prerelease:V+', '2021-10-06 12:38:17.561 INFO [SessionManager:52] N…lication/json Content-Type header in GET response', '2021-10-06 12:38:17.632 INFO [SessionManager:52] N…lication/json Content-Type header in GET response'];
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text.join("\n")));
element.setAttribute('download', filename);

element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);

element.click();

document.body.removeChild(element);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you say `encodeURIComponent(text)` the text array is converted to a string which means that items are concatenated with just a comma. Then that big string is passed to `encodeURIComponent` and the comma is also encoded. I would suggest to use `encodeURIComponent` upfront and then join the items with a new line. For example:

```js
var filename = "log.txt";
var text = ['2021-10-06 12:38:15.946 INFO [conftest:101] Global Fixture Setup Started --------------', '2021-10-06 12:38:16.059 INFO [Wrapper:21] Downloading  from ar:', '2021-10-06 12:38:16.061 INFO [Handler:55] …ct: 1/1 - com.grundfos.hvp.xconnect-prerelease:V+', '2021-10-06 12:38:17.561 INFO [SessionManager:52] N…lication/json Content-Type header in GET response', '2021-10-06 12:38:17.632 INFO [SessionManager:52] N…lication/json Content-Type header in GET response'];
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text.join('\n'));
element.setAttribute('download', filename);

element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);

element.click();

document.body.removeChild(element);
```

The key moment is to replace `encodeURIComponent(text)` with `encodeURIComponent(text.join('\n'))`.

Comment: It should `join` before `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: Aaah I see ;) It works now, didn't know that it could be done like this, thanks!

Comment: @MadsSanderHøgstrup, why would you accept this answer instead of @Tom one? This one doesn't work at all. It should `join("\n")` before `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: Well it worked for me, but other answer also works

Comment: @ikhvjs it depends on what the OP wants actually. I thought that the idea is to have new lines in the file at the end. If you do join and then encode instead of new lines you'll get just "%0A".

Comment: If you don’t encode the \n character, you cannot download the file. You can try to run your code in your local environment.

Comment: Ah I missed that. Makes sense. Changing my answer.